# custom error page for folder protected by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

I want to send the user to a custom error message when an incorrect username of password is used.  I still get the default error message along with a message that ErrorDocument line is incorrect.  I don't know what is wrong with the code Please help.  This is my code

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/aoswald/njlti.aoswald/pubs/.htpasswd
AuthName "Publications Area"
require valid-user
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(?:www\.)?njlti\.aoswald\.com(?:$|/) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif)$ - [F,NC]
ErrorDocument 401 http://njlti.aoswald.com/401.html
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can not use full URL in ErrorDocument
but something like this:

ErrorDocument 401 /401.html

reference: http://tosbourn.com/notice-cannot-use-a-full-url-in-a-401-errordocument-directive-ignoring/